# Passport-related question

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I recently  obtained a new passport, the old one having the information of my guardian as I was under age , When I left my country after getting it, I used the  new passport as it is the current one, but I entered Turkey using the old passport, as I have a permit card that has been registered under it.
Could this be a problem? What can I do? I must go and let them know of the change. I have been to the embassy of my country, and they gave me a supporting document informing of the change. However, would the stamp in my new passport showing I left my country be a problem, as the entry stamp from Turkey is in my old passport?

Comment: Which country is "your country"?

Comment: Why would you have a passport with the information of your guardian in it, and why would that be a reason for getting a new passport? What information does your new passport show in the place where your old one showed the information of your guardian?  Was your old passport cancelled when the new one was issued?

Comment: Hi there thank you so much for replying , my old passport wasn't canceled apparently as I used it to enter here as this is where my permit is registered . My passport had my guardians information in it as the time I was getting it I was underage and had no ID so they used my guardians and then was told my tiny embassy in Turkey to go back to Zambia and have it changed which I did and when leaving used the new one but getting here used the old one as I have the permit card lodged in it, and didn't transfer it to my new passport yet

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Everything you answer in comments should be in the question too, because comments can disappear. And answer Nate's question please.

Comment: My apologies I'm new to this , to answer Nate's question , of which was wrongly put in my question not "my country " but country of nationality , which is Zambia .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your old passport has a valid endorsement (like a visa stamp), you should carry it with you.

At the border, ask the immigration officer if you need to transfer the visa to your new passport. Sometimes, they don't need you to as long as you carry both passports with you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this . I mentioned that leaving my country I used my new passport and so it has this stamp and entering Turkey used my old passport as it is what they have in the system until it is changed could that stamp in my new passport when leaving my country pose a problem ? Kindly assist

Comment: All new stamps can only be done on your new passport, as the old one is no longer valid. So there is no issue with half of the stamp being on the old one, and the other half on the new one. Don't worry about this. Just make sure you carry both passports with you.

Comment: Thank you so very much Burhan I'm really worried about it I am back in Turkey to enter here they stamped the old passport and have been told to go and tell them of the change of passport the stamp of leaving my country iOS in the new one but the old one was stamped here as in their system that is where the permit is registered I'm really scared about it if they check in it and ask about that stamp

Comment: Is*sorry about the typing errors